# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory::getCacheDriver()

Tags: symfony

He actualizado a `Symfony 5.4.8` y al intentar acceder a la aplicación me salta el error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getCacheDriver" of class
> "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory".
>
> Uncaught PHP Exception
> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\UndefinedMethodError: "Attempted
> to call an undefined method named "getCacheDriver" of class
> "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory"." at
> C:\wamp64\www\pami54.local\vendor\gedmo\doctrine-extensions\src\Mapping\ExtensionMetadataFactory.php
> line 104

Desde `ExtensionMetadataFactory` de la librería `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` se llama a esa función, pero la verdad es que no la encuentro en todo `/vendor/doctrine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la úlitma actualización de gedmo/doctrine-extension se elimina la dependencia de la getCacheDriver(), aunque inicialmente la solución encontrada fue fijar en el composer.json a la versión 3.6.0 de dicha librería.

Answer (score 3):

ese funciona para mi:

```
composer req doctrine/persistence:^2.2
```

El problema es en doctrine/persistence 3

Comment: Yo lo que hice fue poner gedmo/doctrine-extension a '^3.6' según la respuesta al issue abierto en GITHUB: https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/issues/2448#issuecomment-1113970647

Answer (score 0):

Me pasa casi lo mismo, mismo error, pero yo he actualizado a symfony 6.0.8.

Por ahora lo que he hecho para solucionarlo es downgradear symfony a una versión anterior.

Answer (score -1):

In my composer.json there was no `doctrine/persistence` package required.
So, just running `composer update` fixed the issue

Comment: With the latest update that function was deleted